# ubuntu 20.10 desktop icon duplicated

Tags: desktop-icons

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hxo3b.png

This is how it looks like. I am pretty sure it is a bug, even if it could be fixed by change some setting. Because it just happened after I upgrade to 20.10...  But I don't know which program is in charge of this problem, so cannot use `ubuntu-bug` to report it.

Any hint on fixing it or reporting this bug is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by create a new user and move my files to that new account. There must be something wrong in the .config, .local or some other "dot directories".